# How to make Django values() exclude some fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

I have multiple models which has fields like "created_at" "updated_at" which I don't want to get with `objects.values()`.

Does Django has any way to exclude fields in **values()**?

I know people refer to `defer()`, but it doesn't return `QuerySet<Dict>` like `values()` instead returns `QuerySet<Model>`.

I tried `objects.defer("created_at", "updated_at").values()`, but it includes those 2 deferred fields in the resulting Dict.

I see `defer().query` only selecting the non-exluded fields in the SQL, but using `defer(..).values()` resets the deferred fields and selects **all** fields.

I cannot specify which field I want, since different model has different fields, I can only specity which fields I don't want. So I cannot use `values('name', 'age', ...)`

I'm planning to use a CustomeManager, which I can use in all model.

Example:

```py
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def values_excluded(self):
        return self.values() # somehow exlude the fields and return QuerySet<Dict>

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = CustomManager()

ExampleModel.objects.values_excluded()
```

Is there any way in Django or do I have to manually delete those keys from the resulting Dict from `values()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):

    def values_excluded(self, *excluded_fields):
        included_fields = [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields if f.name not in excluded_fields]
        return self.values(*included_fields)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
esclude_fields = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
keys = [f.name for f in Model._meta.local_fields if f.name not in esclude_fields]
queryset.values(*keys)
```